# Selenium Can't open IE10 in windows 7 server by write Selenium Code

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

**I received error message with new windows as "Internet explorer has stopped working "**

I tried by enable/disable protect mode for all zones , google help solutions . I download IEDriverServer_x64_2.42.0 and selenium-java-2.42.2. I have added jar files from selenium 2.4.2 to my project library by add build path .

my code is :

```
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
    capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);
    capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
    capabilities.setCapability("silent", true);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\IEDriverServer_x64_2.42.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new  InternetExplorerDriver();
```

I am not able to open IE browser in Windows7 Server 64 bit ,IE 9 Version.

I am able to open all browsers including IE in windows8, IE11 Versions .

I have attached screenshot with error message and code .

I will share my screen over team viewer .

Below is the error log:

> Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
>
> 2.42.0.0
>
> Listening on port 2878
>
> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. IELaunchURL() returned HRESULT 80070012 ('There are no more files.') for URL 'localhost:2878/'
>
> (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>
> Command duration or timeout: 21.72 seconds
>
> Build info: version: '2.42.2', revision: '6a6995d', time: '2014-06-03 17:42:30'
>
> System info: host: 'ASD-T-MADHUA1', ip: '192.168.0.30', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_05'
>
> Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
>
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:162)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:240)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:225)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.run(InternetExplorerDriver.java:182)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.(InternetExplorerDriver.java:174)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.(InternetExplorerDriver.java:146)
>   at UIControls.InternetExplorer.main(InternetExplorer.java:41)

Comment: I am not able to open IE browser in Windows7 Server 64 bit ,IE 9 Version.

I am able to open all browsers including IE in wondows8, IE11 Versions .
 
I have attached screenshot with error message and code .

Comment: Clearly you haven't set the protected mode settings correctly as I can see this: `capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);`

Comment: by remove firefox setting , i resolved this ...

Comment: Please can you elaborate a bit more? What Firefox settings did you remove? Obviously I also tried by setting protected mode to same value for all zones and didn't work.

Comment: we have firewall  settings for open browser , go to firewall application and remove browsers.exe